# why building flink-avro downloads SNAPSHOT flink jars

Tags: apache-flink

a question about building flink-avro.

i downloaded the source, and i am able to build complete source.

but when i move to folder

```
flink/flink-staging/flink-avro
```

and run command `mvn package` as i want to compile and run the tests, it starts downloading latest flink SNAPSHOT jars. 
whereas, i have built the same jars from source, everything is there in local repo.

why it downloads the same things which are built locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mvn install` on the top level module first. This will copy the built jars into your local maven repository located at `~/.m2/respository/`. `mvn package` only builds the jars and put them in folder `target` (no copying into local maven repo happens).

After that, you can step into `flink-avro` and build there (either with `mvn package` or `mvn install` -- as long as no other module depends on the built jars, `mvn package` is fine). If you change something in a module A and another module B depend on A, you need to do `mvn install` in module A. Otherwise, module B cannot access the newly built jars from A.

Maven always looks for dependent jars in your local m2-repository first. If it does not find the jars there, it starts downloading them from the Internet. If it finds "old" jars in your local repo, it might still use them (depending on your specified maven update interval). On the other hand, even if you built `mvn install` locally, and a newer version is available online, maven might download the newer version.

Last but not least, sometime maven does not resolve the timestamp dependencies correctly or does not update the local repo even if you do a `mvn install`. Clearing the local maven repository (just do a `rm` for the corresponding jars or the whole repo) can resolve this problem.